# how to give airdroid root permissions on kitkat?

Tags: root-access, external-sd, file-permissions, airdroid

i have a rooted S4 Mini on kitkat 4.4.2

now they have changed the permission so normal applications cannot write expect a given location on the external sd card. (which is not bad as security).

but now i cant use airdroid to upload files to my mobile.

so instead of allowing all applications to write on the external sd card.

i want to give airdroid root so it can write on the external sd card in any location while the  other applications are controlled by the new rule.

Comment: Are you asking about the same device which already has root? If not, you should change the question asking how to obtain root on the different device. The fact it is Kit Kat doesn't make any difference.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by asking about the same device which already has root.
i already have root on the device.
well the permissions of external SD card changed on kitkat , so this why i did mention kitkat.

Comment: Functionality of Air Droid cannot be changed. It either does root access or it doesn't. Many apps have an option to do root access. To use the option the device must be rooted, otherwise the app works without the option. If you are rooted and Air Droid doesn't access the way you want, there isn't anything you can do but get a different app. Kit Kat has a security feature restricting access to external storage. Some apps have a workaround, some do not.

Comment: thanks .
seems i will enable all apps to write to the external SD card.